# What is the best way to write this recursion logic?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write depth first traversal logic for a probability tree.  Here is some sample code of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
public class ProbBranch
{
    public virtual void Execute()
    {
        // Consequence of this probability branch determined by derived class
    }

    public virtual double GetProbability()
    {
        // Returns the probability chance of the probability branch determined by derived
        // class
        return 1.0;
    }
}

public class ProbTree
{
    public ProbTree[] DependencyTrees { get; set; }
    public ProbBranch[] ProbBranches { get; set; }

    public Reset()
    {
        // Calls other methods in the application to reset the state back to initial
        // values
    }

    public double GetBranchOverallProbability(int branchKey)
    {
        double overallProbability = 0.0;
        double currentProbability = 1.0;
        double[] branchProbability = double[DependencyTrees.Length];
        if (DependencyTrees[0].ProbBranches[0].GetProbability() > 0)
        {
            branchProbability[0] = DependencyTrees[0].ProbBranches[0].GetProbability();
            Reset();
            DependencyTrees[0].branch[0].Execute();
            if (DependencyTrees[1].branch[0].GetProbability() > 0)
            {
                branchProbability[1] = DependencyTrees[1].branch[0].GetProbability();
                Reset();
                DependencyTrees[0].branch[0].Execute();
                DependencyTrees[1].branch[0].Execute();
                ...
                if (DependencyTrees[n-1].branch[0].GetProbability() > 0)
                {
                    branchProbability[n-1] = DependencyTrees[n-1].branch[0].GetProbability();
                    Reset();
                    DependencyTrees[0].branch[0].Execute();
                    DependencyTrees[1].branch[0].Execute();
                    ...
                    DependencyTrees[n-1].branch[0].Execute();
                    if (DependencyTrees[n].branch[0].GetProbability() > 0)
                    {
                        branchProbability[n] = DependencyTrees[n].branch[0].GetProbability();
                        Reset();
                        DependencyTrees[0].branch[0].Execute();
                        DependencyTrees[1].branch[0].Execute();
                        ...
                        DependencyTrees[n-1].branch[0].Execute();
                        DependencyTrees[n].branch[0].Execute();
                        if (ProbBranches[branchKey].GetProbability() > 0)
                        {
                            currentProbability = 1.0;
                            foreach (double prob in branchProbability)
                            {
                                currentProbability *= prob
                            }
                            currentProbability *= ProbBranches[branchKey].GetProbability();
                            overallProbability += currentProbability;
                        }
                    }
                    if (DependencyTrees[n].branch[1].GetProbability() > 0)
                    {
                        branchProbability[n] = DependencyTrees[n].branch[1].GetProbability();
                        Reset();
                        DependencyTrees[0].branch[0].Execute();
                        DependencyTrees[1].branch[0].Execute();
                        ...
                        DependencyTrees[n-1].branch[0].Execute();
                        DependencyTrees[n].branch[1].Execute();
                        if (ProbBranches[branchKey].GetProbability() > 0)
                        {
                            currentProbability = 1.0;
                            foreach (double prob in branchProbability)
                            {
                                currentProbability *= prob
                            }
                            currentProbability *= ProbBranches[branchKey].GetProbability();
                            overallProbability += currentProbability;
                        }
                    }
                    ...
```

Each entry in DependencyTrees needs its branches to be evaluated for its probability, then perform the consequences of the branch and move to the next tree.  Once all branches have been evaluated, multiply through the individual probabilities and get the probability of the branch specified in the parameter.  Once the end of the tree is reached, I want to start evaluating the other branches of the most distant branches first.

I want to write recursion to be able to perform this logic for n-DependencyTrees, but I'm having difficulty conceptualizing the recursion loops that would accomplish this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for all of the input.  I don't think I was clear in what I'm trying to do.  The way my application works is there are many paths to a specific probability point.

For instance, Tree A has outcome 1, 2, and 3.  Tree B has outcome 4, 5, and 6.  Outcome 1 and outcome 4 cannot occur together, Outcome 6 can only occur with outcome 2, etc.

My first attempt to model this as one large tree and enumerate all possibilities and use a recursive method similar to what was suggested below.  This led to an impractical number of objects being created, most of which were duplicates of existing objects only with different parents.

This attempt is to separate this into different probability trees and "wire" them together, but I cannot come up with scaleable logic to do so.

It's very possible that there's a better structure that I'm not thinking of and would appreciate any input.  What I want is to calculate the probability of reaching a particular outcome from all available "paths".

Comment: You should make the base class and its methods [abstract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract), as they contain no implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I simplified the code for presentation here.  In the actual application, I have some implementation in both that is used by most derived classes, but it may be worth considering making one or both abstract and implementing it entirely in the derived class.

Comment: You're asking for the "best" method without saying what your measure for "bestness" is.  Fastest? Shortest? Easiest to understand? Most robust in the face of malformed data?

Comment: FYI coincidentally I have just started writing a series of blog articles on possible improvements to stochastic programming techniques; eventually I will get to elegant ways to represent dependent probabilities, but it's going to take a while to get there. If that subject interests you, see my blog for details.

Comment: I am having some difficulty understanding your code but it looks like you *might* be attempting to implement probabilistic workflows by simulating coroutines with multishot continuations, yes? If the coroutine needs to start again with different parameters, we often see a "reset" operation.

Comment: To address your actual question: the way you write a recursive algorithm is you always start with the base case: that is the case that requires no further recursion. Can you concisely describe for me your base case?

Comment: Re: your edit: Since you now say that you are in a situation where the outcomes are observed to obey certain conditions, that complicates things considerably; is it the case that you're trying to compute a posterior given observations? (Like "outcome 1 is not observed if outcome 4 is observed" and so on) If the weight of each outcome is known -- if everything here is a categorical distribution -- then there are techniques for efficiently computing the posteriors, but as the number of possible combinations goes up, it may be computationally infeasible.

Comment: And again, I'll be covering how to do that sort of thing in C# on my blog over the next couple of months. In the meanwhile, you might consider investigating whether a Probabilistic Programming Language gives you better results than trying to express these workflows in C#. Check out WebPPL for example; if you're already familiar with JavaScript, you should be able to pick it up.

Comment: To briefly answer your question "is there a better data structure?" the data structure I'm going to explore is: *probability distributions form an additive monad*, where the zero is the distribution that throws when sampled because its support is empty. Conditioned probabilities for computing posteriors are the "where" operation, projections are the "select" operation, and *application of a likelihood function to the prior is the select-many*. Once you have that data structure, you can manipulate distributions algebraically using LINQ operators in C#.

Comment: In the case of categorical distributions, suppose we have a prior with n possible outcomes, and a likelihood function where each conditional distribution is categorical with maximum m outcomes. The marginal distribution has maximum m*n categories; we then compute posteriors by setting the weights of the non-observed categories to zero and renormalizing. Does that get you any further? The problem of course is, what happens when m and n get large; their product gets larger.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the structure. A tree is made up of nodes. Either it has child nodes and its probability is calculated as the product of the probabilities of its children, or it has no children, in which case it is a leaf node which must yield its own probability calculated from its own inner state.

```
public abstract class ProbNode
{
    public ProbNode[] ChildNodes { get; set; }

    public abstract double ThisProbability(); // In case it is a leaf node.

    public double OverallProbablility()
    {
        if (ChildNodes == null || ChildNodes.All(n => n == null)) {
            // We have a leaf node
            return ThisProbability();
        } else {
            // We have an internal node.
            // Get the probability as product of the probabilities of the child nodes.
            double p = 1.0;
            foreach (ProbNode child in ChildNodes) {
                if (child != null) {
                    p *= child.OverallProbablility(); // <== Recursive call.
                }
            }
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't clearly see what the purpose of the `Execute` method is, so didn't include it in this example.

Note that this implementation automatically evaluates the most distant nodes first, as each node gets the probabilities of its children, before if can calculate its own.

We don't need a `Tree` class. The tree is simply represented by the root node.

Comment: This could be simplified further if during the probability tree generation it is already known which are leafs and which not. Because then the `ThisProbability` method and the check if it is a leaf node in the `OverallProbability` method could be removed. Leaf nodes are then a derived `ProbLeafNode` class which directly returns its probability in `OverallProbability`.

Comment: Yes, my `ProbNode` would not be abstract and be renamed `ProbInnerNode` and `OverallProbablility` would have to be virtual and contain the recursive code, while `ProbLeafNode` implementations would override `OverallProbablility` and calculate the probability without recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks again for the input.  Unfortunately, I do not have a single parent for each child object in my application.  My application has multiple probability trees whose outcome can (but don't necessarily) affect the probability of the branches of other trees.  This is why the Execute() method is necessary, as it executes the consequences of that branch bring true, and why I need the kind of depth first traversal that I asked about originally.

Comment: This is depth first. (Btw., breadth-first is more complicated to implement). Having several parents should not fundamentally change the algorithm.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how this would work with multiple parent nodes and multiple child nodes.  I'm trying to come up with the probability of reaching this outcome no matter the path used to reach it.  The probability is top down, in this case, not bottom up.

Comment: I don't know either. You seem to have a graph which is not a tree structure at all. Maybe you have to make two passes. Can you tell more about what this structure represents, how it looks like and how the probabilities are calculated by taking in account the children as well as the parents? (Btw., you are talking about branches and trees. Since usually branches make up a tree, it is not clear what the difference is and which are children or parents.